# PHP curl_multi_exec is not working and giving a strange error: 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) and it's giving a strange error. I copied the code straight from the PHP manual. It works in development, but not production. It is quick in development, about 4 seconds. This is the log:

```
2015-11-06T03:00:40.265225+00:00 app[web.2]: [06-Nov-2015 03:00:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
in /app/controllers/ShoppingController.php on line 148
2015-11-06T03:00:40.297189+00:00 app[web.2]: #0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
2015-11-06T03:00:40.297316+00:00 app[web.2]: #1 {main}
2015-11-06T03:00:40.304584+00:00 app[web.2]: [06-Nov-2015 03:00:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
2015-11-06T03:00:40.304698+00:00 app[web.2]: [06-Nov-2015 03:00:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 5 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
2015-11-06T03:00:40.304820+00:00 app[web.2]: [06-Nov-2015 03:00:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
2015-11-06T03:00:40.304916+00:00 app[web.2]: [06-Nov-2015 03:00:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 5 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
```

I can find no web pages with "PHP Warning:  (null)(): 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0". This is the code:

```
if ($ebayRequest) curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ebayRequest);
if ($prosperentRequest) curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $prosperentRequest);

//execute the handles
$curlTime = microtime(true);
$active = null;
do {
  $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
  if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) { # line 148
    do {
      $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
  }
}
```

---

This works, which is what I've been using for now. (Except sometimes this doesn't return the full response.)

```
$running = null;
do { 
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0 || $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
```

Comment: one suggestion is use `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: I already use `curl_setopt_array` and `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5`.

Comment: see the first error, so try to increase the timeout of curl and try it once

Comment: The timeout error is from the server, Heroku. It executes in less than 2-4s in development. It is not possible to increase execution limit over 30s in production.

Comment: check curl verbose, may be server firewall is blocking the things

Comment: It works using regular `curl_exec` so it isn't a firewall.